# How to import extended marque for android?

Tags: android

I´m trying to import to my project this library, but in the graddle when i try to sync it appears this error:

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: asia.ivity.android:marqueeview:{insert-latest-version}
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/OFTECNICA2/Desktop/APPs-Proyectos/EjemploScroll/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

This is the [library](https://github.com/ened/Android-MarqueeView), what can I do?

Edit:

I have added the graddle to obtain more help:

Graddle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.oftecnica2.ejemploscroll"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Graddle project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: it's working fine.... You need to update the latest gradle to your code...

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Change the Version build to latest....

Comment: i have added the graddle, what should i change?

Comment: compile project(':library')... add in dependecy Or you can direct use the files..

if lib add than  also change in setting.gradle include ':library', ':sample'

Comment: Try the Link full project or.. with code directly and let me know

Answer (score 0):

@Sergio Forget to library you can the code of library to own project...

[For sample link working code..Here Working Code](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/fe0ac6f5d2395f62e5e431f70ec8136d20160901114627/527e81)

> MarqueeViewSample.java

```
package asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

import asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView;

public class MarqueeViewSample extends Activity {
    final static String[] randomStrings = new String[]{
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed.", "do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
        "fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat", "sunt in culpa qui officia", "nisi ut aliquid",
        "aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur", "inventore veritatis et quasi architecto",
        "beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem"
    };

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Marquee #1: Configuration using code.
    final MarqueeView mv = (MarqueeView) findViewById(R.id.marqueeView100);
    mv.setPauseBetweenAnimations(500);
    mv.setSpeed(10);
    getWindow().getDecorView().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        mv.startMarquee();
        }
    });

    final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    getWindow().getDecorView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        textView1.setText(randomStrings[new Random().nextInt(randomStrings.length)]);
        mv.startMarquee();
        }
    }, 1000);

    // Marquee #2: Configured via XML.
    final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    findViewById(R.id.btnChangeText).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        textView2.setText(randomStrings[new Random().nextInt(randomStrings.length)]);
        }
    });

    // Marquee #3: Manual Start/Stop
    final MarqueeView marqueeView3 = (MarqueeView) findViewById(R.id.marqueeView3);
    findViewById(R.id.btnStart).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        marqueeView3.startMarquee();
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.btnStop).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        marqueeView3.reset();
        }
    });
    }


}
```

> main.xml

asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView change according to your path marqueeView Have path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:marquee="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:text="First MarqueeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />

    <asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView
        android:id="@+id/marqueeView100"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do."
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
    </asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView>

    <TextView
        android:text="Second MarqueeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />

    <!--Marquee #2: Configuration using XML attributes.-->
    <asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView
        android:id="@+id/marqueeView150"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        marquee:speed="5"
        marquee:pause="1000"
        marquee:autoStart="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
    </asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeText"
        android:text="Change MarqueeView 2 text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Second MarqueeView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />

    <!--Marquee #3: Configuration using XML attributes. -->
    <!--Marquee #3: Start / Stop manually. -->
    <asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView
        android:id="@+id/marqueeView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        marquee:speed="10"
        marquee:pause="700"
        marquee:autoStart="false"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do."
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
    </asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStop"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:text="Start"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MarqueeView.java

```
package asia.ivity.android.marqueeview;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.sample.BuildConfig;
import asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.sample.R;

/**
 * Provides a simple marquee effect for a single {@link TextView}.
 *
 * @author Sebastian Roth <sebastian.roth@gmail.com>
 */
public class MarqueeView extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView mTextField;

    private ScrollView mScrollView;

    private static final int TEXTVIEW_VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 2000;

    private Animation mMoveTextOut = null;
    private Animation mMoveTextIn = null;

    private Paint mPaint;

    private boolean mMarqueeNeeded = false;

    private static final String TAG = MarqueeView.class.getSimpleName();

    private float mTextDifference;

    /**
     * Control the speed. The lower this value, the faster it will scroll.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_SPEED = 60;

    /**
     * Control the pause between the animations. Also, after starting this activity.
     */
    private static final int DEFAULT_ANIMATION_PAUSE = 2000;

    private int mSpeed = DEFAULT_SPEED;

    private int mAnimationPause = DEFAULT_ANIMATION_PAUSE;

    private boolean mAutoStart = false;

    private Interpolator mInterpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    private boolean mCancelled = false;
    private Runnable mAnimationStartRunnable;

    private boolean mStarted;

    /**
     * Sets the animation speed.
     * The lower the value, the faster the animation will be displayed.
     *
     * @param speed Milliseconds per PX.
     */
    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.mSpeed = speed;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the pause between animations
     *
     * @param pause In milliseconds.
     */
    public void setPauseBetweenAnimations(int pause) {
        this.mAnimationPause = pause;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a custom interpolator for the animation.
     *
     * @param interpolator Animation interpolator.
     */
    public void setInterpolator(Interpolator interpolator) {
        this.mInterpolator = interpolator;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
    public MarqueeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
    public MarqueeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        init();
        extractAttributes(attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public MarqueeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init();
        extractAttributes(attrs);
    }

    private void extractAttributes(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (getContext() == null) {
            return;
        }

        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.asia_ivity_android_marqueeview_MarqueeView);

        if (a == null) {
            return;
        }

        mSpeed = a.getInteger(R.styleable.asia_ivity_android_marqueeview_MarqueeView_speed, DEFAULT_SPEED);
        mAnimationPause = a.getInteger(R.styleable.asia_ivity_android_marqueeview_MarqueeView_pause, DEFAULT_ANIMATION_PAUSE);
        mAutoStart = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.asia_ivity_android_marqueeview_MarqueeView_autoStart, false);

        a.recycle();
    }

    private void init() {
        // init helper
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        mInterpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        if (getChildCount() != 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("MarqueeView must have exactly one child element.");
        }

        if (changed && mScrollView == null) {
            if (!(getChildAt(0) instanceof TextView)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The child view of this MarqueeView must be a TextView instance.");
            }

            initView(getContext());

            prepareAnimation();

            if (mAutoStart) {
                startMarquee();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts the configured marquee effect.
     */
    public void startMarquee() {
        if (mMarqueeNeeded) {
            startTextFieldAnimation();
        }

        mCancelled = false;
        mStarted = true;
    }

    private void startTextFieldAnimation() {
        mAnimationStartRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mTextField.startAnimation(mMoveTextOut);
            }
        };
        postDelayed(mAnimationStartRunnable, mAnimationPause);
    }

    /**
     * Disables the animations.
     */
    public void reset() {
        mCancelled = true;

        if (mAnimationStartRunnable != null) {
            removeCallbacks(mAnimationStartRunnable);
        }

        mTextField.clearAnimation();
        mStarted = false;

        mMoveTextOut.reset();
        mMoveTextIn.reset();

        cutTextView();

        invalidate();
    }

    private void prepareAnimation() {
        // Measure
        mPaint.setTextSize(mTextField.getTextSize());
        mPaint.setTypeface(mTextField.getTypeface());
        float mTextWidth = mPaint.measureText(mTextField.getText().toString());

        // See how much functions are needed at all
        mMarqueeNeeded = mTextWidth > getMeasuredWidth();

        mTextDifference = Math.abs((mTextWidth - getMeasuredWidth())) + 5;

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mTextWidth       : " + mTextWidth);
            Log.d(TAG, "measuredWidth    : " + getMeasuredWidth());
            Log.d(TAG, "mMarqueeNeeded   : " + mMarqueeNeeded);
            Log.d(TAG, "mTextDifference  : " + mTextDifference);
        }

        final int duration = (int) (mTextDifference * mSpeed);

        mMoveTextOut = new TranslateAnimation(0, -mTextDifference, 0, 0);
        mMoveTextOut.setDuration(duration);
        mMoveTextOut.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
        mMoveTextOut.setFillAfter(true);

        mMoveTextIn = new TranslateAnimation(-mTextDifference, 0, 0, 0);
        mMoveTextIn.setDuration(duration);
        mMoveTextIn.setStartOffset(mAnimationPause);
        mMoveTextIn.setInterpolator(mInterpolator);
        mMoveTextIn.setFillAfter(true);

        mMoveTextOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                expandTextView();
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (mCancelled) {
                    reset();
                    return;
                }

                mTextField.startAnimation(mMoveTextIn);
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        mMoveTextIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                cutTextView();

                if (mCancelled) {
                    reset();
                    return;
                }
                startTextFieldAnimation();
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void initView(Context context) {
        // Scroll View
        LayoutParams sv1lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        sv1lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        mScrollView = new ScrollView(context);

        // Scroll View 1 - Text Field
        mTextField = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
        removeView(mTextField);

        mScrollView.addView(mTextField, new ScrollView.LayoutParams(TEXTVIEW_VIRTUAL_WIDTH, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        mTextField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                final boolean continueAnimation = mStarted;

                reset();
                prepareAnimation();

                cutTextView();

                post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (continueAnimation) {
                            startMarquee();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        addView(mScrollView, sv1lp);
    }

    private void expandTextView() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mTextField.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = TEXTVIEW_VIRTUAL_WIDTH;
        mTextField.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }

    private void cutTextView() {
        if (mTextField.getWidth() != getMeasuredWidth()) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mTextField.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = getMeasuredWidth();
            mTextField.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    }
}
```

> values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


   <resources>

  <declare-styleable name="asia.ivity.android.marqueeview.MarqueeView">
    <attr name="speed" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="pause" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="autoStart" format="boolean"/>
  </declare-styleable>

   </resources>
```

[image]